# Samsung Tab GT P-1000 battery issue

Tags: samsung-mobile

A red cross sign is displayed over the battery level sign when my samsung tab GT P-1000 is connected with a charger

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

this question isn't really for Stack Exchange, in the future you should try posting it on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Regardless, I think it has something to do with the battery not receiving enough power, say for example it's connected to your PC with a USB cable.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer; additional to the off-topic nature, the attempt to answer is speculative rather than canonical in nature. (If you don't have enough reputation to comment, it's appropriate to wait until you *do* have that reputation, rather than add comments as answers).